# replace/substitute a list of substrings in a list of filenames in bash (with awk?)

Tags: bash, awk, substring, filenames, substitution

I found out that in some of my > 100.000 filenames my separator `_` also appears on not expected positions and messes up the processing. Therefore, I would like to replace the `_` in those files. They are all in one folder. I tried to use the awk FILENAME variable, but I don't know how to adress it to change the file name itself. Full filenames are e.g.

```
mg.reads.per.gene_Putative@polyhydroxyalkanoic@acid@system@protein@(PHA_gran_rgn)_A1.tsv   
mg.reads.per.gene_Phage@regulatory@protein@Rha@(Phage_pRha)_A1.tsv 
...
```

In general, the first and the last `_` are supposed to be there, all additional ones should be replaced. Note: the additional ones are not always in brackets. I generated a list with those problematic substrings within the file name called `problems.txt`:

```
Putative@polyhydroxyalkanoic@acid@system@protein@(PHA_gran_rgn)
Phage@regulatory@protein@Rha@(Phage_pRha)
Phage@tail@protein@(Tail_P2_I)
Phd_YefM
pheT_bact:@phenylalanine--tRNA@ligase%2C@beta@subunit
...
```

and would here also like to use `@` as uncommon character to get:

```
mg.reads.per.gene_Putative@polyhydroxyalkanoic@acid@system@protein@(PHA@gran@rgn)_A1.tsv    
mg.reads.per.gene_Phage@regulatory@protein@Rha@(Phage@pRha)_A1.tsv 
...
```

how do I use this list as input to change only those filenames matching the records in the list? I tried this to adresse the files within the folder and change part of the filename (awk Pseudocode):

```
for sample_files in $(find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f)
do  
  awk '{if ("problem_record" ~ FILENAME); 
  gsub(/_/,/@/, substring(FILENAME))); print}' problems.txt $sample_files > $sample_files
done
```

but I'm can't specify that I only want the changes within the area covered by the "problem_record" entries. I'm also don't know how to specify the output

Comment: Sorry, this is not the way StackOverflow works. Questions of the form "I want to do X, please give me tips and/or sample code" are considered off-topic. Please visit the [help] and read [ask], and especially read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236). So in short, what did you try?

Comment: I added my approach but it is mainly pseudocode as I actually don't know how to get further, that's why I posted here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a pure bash solution:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Loop over all files in the current directory
for i in *; do

  # Extract the part before the first _
  head="${i%%_*}"

  # Get the rest of the string
  tail="${i#*_}"

  # Extract the part after the last _
  rhead="${tail##*_}"

  # Extract the "middle" portion
  rtail="${tail%_*}"

  # Substitute _ with @ in the "middle"
  fixedrtail="${rtail//_/@}"

  # Rename files
  #echo -e "Renaming \"$i\" to \"$head_${fixedrtail}_$rhead\""
  mv $i "${head}_${fixedrtail}_${rhead}"
done
```

This takes all the files in the current directory and renames them such that all `_`, except the first and the last ones are replaced with a `@`. It uses lots of parameter expansion, which you can [read about here](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#search_and_replace).

Comment: perfect, it works. I will have a look into the expansions. One more thing (probably related to this): from all my entries, exactly one was ignored: `mg.reads.per.gene_Penicillin-binding@protein@4*_A5.tsv` I can't understand how people can use `*` in a file name ;-)

Comment: @crazysantaclaus I think it might've been mishandled because of inconsistent quoting on my part. Bash usually handles it well if one quotes correctly. I'll fix and update the answer.